# Java iterator nested List

Tags: android

I have simple Class structure as :

```
public class MessagesList {
    private int id;
    private int msg_id;
}
```

for get and set data for database,o'm using this code :

```
List<MessagesList> item = 
       G.dbHelper.getRawRow("SELECT * FROM messageslist GROUP BY msg_id");
```

to get query from database, result is:

```
item = {ArrayList@830033903920}  size = 2

 0 = {String[14]@830033903944} 
    0 = {String@830033904024} "1"
    1 = {String@830033904080} "1"
 1 = {String[14]@830033905064} 
    0 = {String@830033905144} "2"
    1 = {String@830033905200} "2"
```

now I'm trying to iterator this nested List by :

```
    for (int i=0;i<item.size();i++) {
        Log.e("",item.get(i).getId()+"");

    }
```

I get error and my app dont work, how to iterator this nested List? thanks

**Error:**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String[] 
>       cannot be cast to ir.tsms.EitaaPro.Helper.Database.Models.MessagesList

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
List<MessagesList> item = 
       G.dbHelper.getRawRow("SELECT * FROM messageslist GROUP BY msg_id");
```

String object is coming from the database.

Solution: get length of your data and get it one by one.
like :

```
List<MessagesList> item=new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i yourDataLength;i++)
{
    item.add( MessageList data from the database);
}
```